# How to pass variables to inline css function in React

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router

I' ve managed to create class in React and wanted to set random generated background to div container. Const variable named divStyle does include CSS function rbg() but I just can't find solution to Pass variables from this.state to that function

```
import React from 'react';
import './ShopItem.css';

class ShopItem extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        r:Math.floor(Math.random() * 256),
        g:Math.floor(Math.random() * 256),
        b:Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)        
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.state.r, this.state.g, this.state.b);
} 

render(){

    const divStyle = {
        background: "rgb()"
    };

    return(
        <div className="Item" style={divStyle} >
            {console.log("test")}
            {this.props.data}
        </div>
    );
};
};

export default ShopItem;
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use es6 backticks and just add use the following code, `this` refers to the current instance, so `this.state` is available inside the methods.

```
const divStyle = {
    background: `rgb(${this.state.r},${this.state.g},${this.state.b})`
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add them to the string:

```
const divStyle = {
    background: "rgb(" + this.state.r + "," + this.state.g + "," + this.state.b + ")"
};
```

Answer (score -3):

Writing inline styles can quickly become verbose, hard to maintain  and ugly. I'd look at styled-components as a solution to your problem. That seems to me to be a much more flexible solution to dynamically changing styling on React components

Here is the link
https://www.styled-components.com/